# Palmer's Algorithm for Hamiltonian cycles

Tags: algorithm, graph, traveling-salesman, hamiltonian-cycle

In a "dense" graph, I am trying to construct a Hamiltonian cycle using [Palmer's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem). However, I need more explanation for this algorithm because it does not work with me when I implement it. It seems that there is an unclear part in Wikipedia's explanation.

I would be thankful if someone explains it more clearly or give me some links to read.

Here's the algorithm statement:

> Palmer (1997) describes the following simple algorithm for constructing a Hamiltonian cycle in a graph meeting Ore's condition.
>   Arrange the vertices arbitrarily into a cycle, ignoring adjacencies in the graph.
>   While the cycle contains two consecutive vertices `vi` and `vi + 1` that are not adjacent in the graph, perform the following two steps:
>
> - Search for an index `j` such that the four vertices `vi`, `vi + 1`, `vj`, and `vj + 1` are all distinct and such that the graph contains edges from `vi` to `vj + 1` and from `vj` to `vi + 1`
> - Reverse the part of the cycle between `vi + 1` and `vj` (inclusive).

To be more specific, I do not get the part where they say:
"Arrange the vertices arbitrarily into a cycle"
in this case, is this right to do: 0,1,2,3,4,0

and what do they mean by: "Reverse the part of the cycle"?

Comment: It's better if you put your try here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, [wikipedia's description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem#Algorithm) of the algorithm <del>is¹</del> was wrong. Palmer's own description is

> 1. Step 0. Arrange the vertices in a circle.
> 2. Step 1. Look around the boundary, say in the counterclockwise direction, for consecutive nonadjacent vertices, i.e., a gap. If there are no gaps, quit with the spanning cycle on the boundary. Otherwise, look for a pair of crossing chords from the vertices of the gap to some other pair of consecutive vertices that may or may not be adjacent (possible gap 2).
>
>    If found, (i.e., gap 1 was good!), simply rearrange the circular order of the vertices in the obvious way so that the two chords become edges on the boundary and the gaps are switched to the interior. Each time we play this game of criss-cross successfully, one or two gaps on the boundary of the circular arrangement of vertices are replaced by two edges. Otherwise repeat Step 1 with the next gap.
>
>    Continue until the spanning cycle is on the boundary, or until every gap is bad.

You need a pair of **crossing** chords, i.e. you need edges

```
v_i <-> v_j
v_{i+1} <-> v_{j+1}
```

That way, by reversing the part from `v_{i+1}` to `v_j` (inclusive), you move the vertex `v_j` - adjacent to `v_i` in the graph - next to `v_i` in your cycle, and the vertex `v_{i+1}` - adjacent to `v_{j+1}` in the graph - is moved next to `v_{j+1}` in the cycle. Thus we obtain two new pairs of neighbours in the cycle that are adjacent in the graph, `(v_i, v_j)` and `(v_{i+1}, v_{j+1})`, and possibly destroy *one* pair of cycle-neighbours that are adjacent in the graph, `(v_j, v_{j+1})`. The number of pairs of cycle-neighbours that are adjacent in the graph increases by 1 or by two each step, so the algorithm terminates.

With the wrong indexing of wikipedia, moving `v_j` next to `v_i` and `v_{i+1}` next to `v_{j+1}` need not generate a new pair of cycle-neighbours that are adjacent in the graph, thus the algorithm need not terminate.

So let's play it through for your example

```
E = { (1,2), (1,3), (1,6), (3,2), (3,4), (5,2), (5,4), (6,4), (6,5) }
```

arranging it as `1426351` initially (no adjacent neighbours).

The first pair of cycle-neighbours not adjacent in the graph is `(1,4) = (v_1,v_2)`. Scan for an index `j > 2` such that `v_j` is adjacent to `v_1` and `v_{j+1}` to `v_2`, the first such occurrence is `j = 3`. Now reverse the part `4...2` in the cycle (in this case, there's no vertex between 4 and 2), giving the next cycle

```
1234561  // index in cycle
1246351  // vertex
```

with two pairs of adjacent neighours (`(1,2)` and `(4,6)`). The first index `i` with `v_i` not adjacent to `v_{i+1}` is 2. Scan for the first `j > 3` such that `v_j` is adjacent to `v_2 = 2` and `v_{j+1}` adjacent to `v_3 = 4`. That gives `j = 5`. Now the part between `v_3` and `v_5` (inclusive), giving the next cycle

```
1234561  // index in cycle
1236451  // vertex
```

Once more, `v_3 = 3` is not adjacent to `v_4 = 6`, so `i = 3`, `j = 5`, reversing yields

```
1234561  // index in cycle
1234651  // vertex
```

Now the only bad pair is `(v_6,v_1) = (5,1)`. The smallest `j > 1` such that `v_j` is adjacent to `v_6 = 5` and `v_{j+1}` to `v_1 = 1` is `j = 2`. Now reverse the part from `v_1` to `v_2` yielding

```
1234561  // index in cycle
2134652  // vertex
```

which is a Hamiltonian cycle.

¹ I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel, I also noticed that Wikipedia made that mistake but I solved it in a different way than yours....Maybe similar but not exactly the same. Anyway Problem solved....Thank you for your effort....I checked your solution and made sure it works....By the way, do you know what should I do in this case (when Wikipedia makes such mistake)...I mean readers will suffer like me. (I have been suffering for 3 weeks).

Comment: If you find an error in a Wikipedia article, correct it (and give a reason why the old one was wrong), it's a wiki. Unrelated, instead of posting a non-answer, you should have commented on my answer, that would also have notified me. (But, I see your gravatar is different, so it's not your question, as far as the system is concerned, and you couldn't comment on it from that account. Wouldn't it be better to merge your accounts?)

Answer (score 1):

> in this case, is this right to do: 0,1,2,3,4,0

Yes. You might get a faster solution by starting from a more carefully chosen initial cycle however the algorithm will succeed starting from any valid initial cycle provided that the graph meets Ore's condition.

> and what do they mean by: "Reverse the part of the cycle"?

It means take the path from vi + 1 to vj and reverse it so that if you started with:

```
vi, vi + 1, vi + 2, vj - 2, vj - 1, vj, vj + 1
```

you end up with:

```
vi, vj, vj - 1, vj - 2, vi + 2, vi + 1, vj + 1
```

so that in your example if we choose i = 0 and j = 3, the end result will be:

```
0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 0
```

Here is a link to [Palmer's paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122197002253) (see the reference section in Wikipedia).